# «И даже». Обособлять или нет?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятушка?

`Мне этот твой кот – курам на смех. Он даже мне монетку(,) да и даже полмонетки(,) не может принести.`

А здесь-таки?

`Мне этот твой кот – курам на смех. Он даже мне монетку(,) и даже полмонетки(,) не может принести.`

Comment: Как написать по-русски: *Он даже мне монетку не может принести, (да) и даже полмонетки.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые нужны, это тема **присоединительных** конструкций:

(1) *Мне этот твой кот – курам на смех. Он даже мне монетку, **да и даже** полмонетки, не может принести.*

(2) *Мне этот твой кот – курам на смех. Он даже мне монетку, **и даже** полмонетки, не может принести.*

По семантике здесь  дополнительные  замечания.  **[По Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)**, такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами ***даже**, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, и (‘и притом’), да, **да и**, да и вообще, да и только и др.*

В приведенных предложениях используются **соединения:** (1) ДА И ДАЖЕ, (2) И ДАЖЕ.

(1) Союз ***ДА И*** — присоединительный, ***ДАЖЕ*** — усилительная частица (по  основному значению).

(2) Союз ***И*** также может быть присоединительным, ***ДАЖЕ*** — усилительная частица.

Обратим также внимание на то, что частица "даже" присутствует и в **первой** части предложения, поэтому оборот имеет именно **присоединительный** характер.

**Словарь**

**ДАЖЕ.** **I. частица**. Употр. для выделения и усиления слова или словосочетания, к которому относится. Такое **даже** выговорить страшно.  Было тепло, **даже** жарко. **II. союз.** (присоединяет **чл. предл. или предл.**, вносящие добавления, уточнения с оттенком усил.). Настолько, так (сильно, долго, много и т.п.), что... Читал много, **даже** испортил себе зрение. <**Даже и..**., в зн. союза. = Даже, но с оттенком ещё большего **усиления**.

**ДА, союз.** 1.  2. (**присоединяет** предл. и чл. предл.). Указывает на развитие, дополнение, пояснение высказанной мысли или характеристику, оценку сказанного. Обидели, да ещё как!  **<Да и..., в зн. союза.** Все молчали, да и говорить было не о чем. Одна только душа была рядом, да и той не стало.

**И, союз.** 6. **Присоединяет** предложения или отдельные члены предложения, развивающие, дополняющие, объясняющие высказанную мысль.  Люди часто посмеиваются над ним, и справедливо.

Comment: Предложения нерусские, но здесь подходит второй пункт (о котором недавно говорили), поскольку сужение смысла ("полмонетки" уже важнее, чем "монетка").

Comment: Для особо доходчивых: то есть обособление только слева.

Comment: А сколько, Sharon, вам годиков?

Answer (score 2):

**Лучше, по-моему, вместо запятых использовать тире**:

*Он даже мне монетку — **да и даже полмонетки** — не может принести.*

---

Можно после «даже полмонетки» поставить и восклицательный знак:

*Он даже мне монетку — **да и даже полмонетки!** — не может принести.*

Comment: Вспомогательная/дополнительная ли это информация, если она сужает основной смысл? По сути, более важная информация.